# ttk slider not changing the value of its assigned variable

Tags: python, tkinter, slider, ttk

When creating a `Tkinter` GUI, I created a universal function for my sliders rather than using one for each slider.
This is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import globalvars
globalvars.init()

leftFrame = tk.Tk()

def sliderChanged(value, sliderval, text, label):
    globals()[value] = int(sliderval)
    label.config(text=f"{text}: {globals()[value]}")
    print(globals()[value])
    print(globalvars.mutation_speed)

mutationslider = ttk.Scale(leftFrame, from_=0, to=1000, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,length=200, value=100, style="custom.Horizontal.TScale")
mutationslider.grid(row=1, column=1)
mutationlabel = tk.Label(leftFrame, font=("Helvetica", 11, "bold"), bg='#0000b3', fg="white")
mutationlabel.grid(row=2, column=1)
mutationslider.configure(command=lambda val: sliderChanged(globalvars.mutation_speed, mutationslider.get(), "Mutation Speed", mutationlabel))

leftFrame.mainloop()
```

And the globalvars file:

```py
def init():
    global mutation_speed
    mutation_speed = 100
```

While the label is updating as is the printed value from the `print(globals()[value])` statement, the actual value I am attempting to change (`globalvars.mutation_speed`) is not changing (it stays at the initial value of `100`).  I believe the issue is with the line `globals()[value] = int(sliderval)` or lies in the way that particular argument is passed/used in the function.
Using Python `3`.

Comment: Note that you pass the value of `globalvars.mutation_speed` as the argument `value` to `sliderChanged()`, so `globals()[value]` is the same as `globals()[100]` which creates an new item in the dictionary `globals()` with key `100`, not referencing `globalvars.mutation_speed`.  You need to find another way to do what you want.

Comment: Could you suggest a method?